# Validate a decimal number typed with thousand separator

Tags: trigger, validation, page-layout

We've defined a custom field in our Tasks that is defined as a Number(8,4), our regional configuration is set to Spanish(Chile) where the thousand separator is period (.) and the decimal separator is a comma (,).

In the PC's keypad, which everyone uses heavily, there's a period and not a comma.

Programs like Excel automatically get the decimal separator from the regional configuration of the machine and replaces the period, obviously this is not the case with Salesforce or anything web related.

As this is typed inside the native Task layout, i cannot add jQuery to validate the input prior to saving or updating.

Validation rules and Triggers receive the inserted value post-processed, for example "1,2" in a trigger (after String.valueOf()) is received as "12".

So the short version of what we're trying to achieve is the following

- 1.2 (invalid, some warning should appear)
- 1,2 (valid, 1 is the integer part and 2 the decimal part)

Thanks in advance

Comment: what locale does the running SFDC user have defined?  SFDC should do proper validation on input per running user's locale

Comment: Both organization and user are set to Español(Chile), my problem is that users use the period (as is right in the keypad) instead of comma, which is our decimal separator, i think SF validates just well as it interprets it as a thousand separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i went with creating string fields for the inputs and doing the validations in a "before insert, before update" trigger created only for this, and then assigning the validated values to their respective number fields.

I'm aware this isn't a direct answer to my problem, but this workaround solved my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a validation rule, you can use something like `AND(CONTAINS(TEXT(fieldname), '.'))` to to detect values like `1.2` and cause them to produce an error message. **Note:** I've assumed you'll need to put TEXT in front of the fieldname. Depending on the type of field, that may not be necessary.

In Apex, you mention `String.valueOf()`, its not clear to me how you're getting `12` from `1.2`, but I've not worked with regional configs to have seen this. I'd think that the toString() method would give you `1,2` and you'd then be able to use some combination of String methods like `contains()`, `replace('.',',')`, `substringBefore('.')`, `substringBetween('.')`, `substringAfter('.')` or `indexOf('.')` to either replace the periods or with commas or declare the data as invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot but as i said this doesn't work, i've tried the contains in the validation rule just as you said. Can you try the other way? i mean typing "1,2" and then checking the value in a trigger, my guess is that you will get "12" thus rendering any before insert attempt to work with the value useless

Comment: I just did an execute anonymous in the dev console of `string.valueOf(decimal_variable)` that had a value of `1.2` stored in it followed by a system.debug and it returned `1.2` which is what I would have expected it to return.

Comment: Should add that I can't test the `1,2` scenario since I can't put that into a decimal variable here.